# GetExecutingAssembly and GetTypes is retrieving an extra type with a "+<>c" suffix which obviously does not exist

Tags: c#

When performing a GetExecutingAssembly with GetTypes, it is retrieving an extra type with a strange "+<>c" suffix to it.  I'm assuming this might be some special character or something?  Shown in image below.  The expected result should just be the 3 items in the list, but it is retrieving an extra 4th item which is a duplicate of one of them but with the "+<>c" at the end?

[image]

I've had to do a bit of a hack check before processing types returned, like this:

```
if (@class.ToString().Contains("<")) // Ignore funny types returned by reflection
                continue;
```

In case it is of interest, general structure of these classes are the same, and are like this:

```
public class WebJobLogsForErrorsCheck : MonitoringJob
{

    public WebJobLogsForErrorsCheck(IKernel kernel) : base(kernel)
    {
    }
 }
```

Comment: web jobs for error check does have any internal class?

Comment: Hi Amit, no, just a public one.   Will update question with that info now

Comment: They are [CompilerGenerated] types, produced by iterators, anonymous methods, lamda expressions, async methods.  Consider to use that attribute to filter them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler has to construct new types at times, and uses "unpronouncable" names - names that no *programmer* could write themselves in a valid C# program<sup>1</sup> - to ensure that the names it creates do not clash.

It will create such types to support, for instance, iterator methods or async methods, both of which in fact have to be implemented behind the scenes as state machines.

---

For this specific case, I believe `<>c` classes tend to be constructed when they're used to cache non-capturing lambdas, as an optimization.

---

<sup>1</sup>It can do this because the set of valid CLR identifiers is a superset of the set of valid C# identifiers.

Comment: I've typically heard them called "unspeakable names", which I believe was coined by Eric Lippert.

Comment: I m trying to do similar (at least what i m seeing in question) but not getting such type ! can you tell me how to get my compiler create such type ?

Comment: Amit - I've given three examples in my answer of situations where the compiler will construct such types - iterator methods or async methods or (for this specific instance) where a non-capturing lambda is used.

Comment: Thanks Damien_The_Unbeliever.  I guess I just need to cater for them.  Amit, I think this 'may' have started around the time that the class did try and perform a .Where(...).ToList() on an already established List.  Not 100% sure though.